# Vanilla JS Algolia InstantSearch - Parsing array data in template

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch.js

I have my data stored in an array of objects and I am successfully parsing the first two values in my template. As they are strings, it’s pretty straightforward -

```
{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "traditional" }{{/helpers.highlight}}
{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "pinyinDiacritic" }{{/helpers.highlight}}
```

I’m trying to do the same for an array of data that I have stored. I’ve tried using the same way as before `({ "attribute": "definitions" })` but no data gets returned.

This makes sense as it’s an array and not a string but how do you parse arrays in an instantsearch template?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write

```js
{{#array}}{{value}}{{/array}}
```